# Fetching Quote Items of Inactive Cart (Abandoned cart)

Tags: magento2, quote, magento2.2.6, quoteitem

I am trying to fetch all the items of a Quote.

First i am load the quote using \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface

with get() method i am getting Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface

using getItems() method of CartInterface i am getting null even when items are in a quote.

If i change the quote status to Active inside quote table then it is showing.

How i can fetch quote item even if it is inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work

$cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();